# NativeScript not synching angular templates and CSS

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is it ok that livesync doesn't automatically updates the app in emulator (Android)? I run the app with `tns run android` and it does submit the edits (angular templates + css), but I need to manually exit and open the app.
When I edit `*.ts`, for example, it refreshes the app normally.

GIF with demonstration: https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohze2CvSPvtz8QHBu/fullscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug introduced with nativeScript 3.0.0 and a fix was released with nativeScript 3.0.1 with [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2780)